# LAG Function over dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select to_date(to_char(order_date, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyymmdd') -
         lag(to_date(to_char(order_date, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyymmdd'), 1, 0)
         over (order by order_id)
from orders
```

I want to find the difference in days between two dates, but when I apply lag function to the date it returns NUMBER value -

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Tried to do some conversions with TO_CHAR, CAST, but it doesn't help much.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The error is caused by the third argument in the second call to `lag`. You are lagging an expression that evaluates to a date. The third argument is supposed to be a default value if the "lag" does not exist (you are applying it to the first row). As such, that third argument should have the same data type as the first. You are using 0, which is a number and can't be implicitly converted to a date. I won't say more, since there are too many other mistakes, but if you just want to know why you get **this** error, here you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `order_date` a `date`?  If so, doing a `to_char` on it just to do a `to_date` on it again is pointless (if you are just trying to set the time component of the `date` to midnight, use `trunc(order_date)`).  Assuming it is a `date`

```
order_date - lag(order_date) over (order by order_id)
```

should be valid syntax.

But it seems unlikely that you want to know the number of days between successive orders (which will almost certainly be a small fraction of a day) rather than, say, the number of days between successive orders for the same customer which would likely involve having a `partition by` clause in your analytic function.

Comment: Yes, it's a date. The query works, but now it rather looks like timestamp and I need to show only the days... should I try to reformat it with to_char?

Comment: @PySquirrel - I'm not sure what "looks like timestamp" means.  It would be a very weird system that had multiple days between orders.  If you want to set the time component of `order_date` to midnight so your calculation always returns an integer number of days, you can `trunc(order_date)`.  If that's not what you want, editing your question to include a reproducible test case (table definition, sample data, query, actual results, expected results, etc) would be helpful.